# Mongoose populate nested not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this user model:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        ...,
        instances: {
            type: Array,
            default: [{
                role: 'user'
            }],
            role: {
                type: String,
                enum: ['admin', 'user']
            },
            company: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Company'
            },
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);
```

And company model:

```
const companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    logo: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'File',
        required: true
    }
}, { timestamps: true });
```

And this pre find method:

```
userSchema.pre('findOne', function () {
    this.populate({
        path: 'instances.company',
        populate: {
            path: 'logo',
            model: 'File'
        }
    });
});
```

I want to populate the instances companies on each find, and populate the logo of the company.
The thing is, that the company is populated, but not the logo path.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the File model is defined (example:mongoose.model('File', File)), so you can omit the 'model' and just do: populate: ['logo']

Comment: Have you created the models or just defined them?